# is there a way of automating $credential = Get-Credential when running Set-AzVMADDomainExtension

Tags: azure

I need to automate domain join in a pipleine for Azure vm , Im using this code, however I dont want the user to enter the credential during runtime, how can i use a saved credential?

```
$DomainName = "abc.com"
$VMName = "VMNAME01"
$credential = Get-Credential
$ResourceGroupName = "RG01" 
Set-AzVMADDomainExtension -DomainName $DomainName -VMName $VMName -Credential $credential -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -JoinOption 0x00000001 -Restart -Verbose
```

Comment: You can try combining the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.secretmanagement/?view=ps-modules) module with the [Azure KeyVault (`Az.KeyVault`)](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.KeyVault) module - see [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/secretmanagement-and-secretstore-are-generally-available/).